# OSX Messages executable

Tags: macos

So I know it is a weird question but basically I copied the Messages app onto my desktop and it ran, but when I changed the executable file inside of the .app, it crashes with Illegal Instruction: 4, which I know is about DYLD, looking into the executable AVCore is hard-located at /Applications/Messages.app/Contents/Frameworks this leads me to ask if the Illegal Instruction is because the AVCore framework is looking for the renamed executable in the /Applications/Messages.app? If not, why is the Illegal Instruction occuring?

Comment: What changes did you make to the executable file inside the App?

Comment: All I did in the app in my desktop is rename the executable, for the app in Applications I did nothing

Comment: Did you change the name of the executable in the Info.plist file as well?

Comment: Yes, I changed the name in the Info.plist